# Measuring Sound Levels on Raspberry Pi with PyAudio

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I am creating a simple sound monitor for the Raspberry Pi with a USB mic in Python that will detect sudden changes in sound, be they 'claps', beats in music, or other noises. I would like it to take a, say, 0.1 second sample compare it with the previous sample period and then send a message (via MQTT) if the new sample exceeds a certain threshold. I've been using PyAudio and audioop.max and have written this:

```
import time, audioop
import pyaudio

# Initialisation for PyAudio
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 1

threshold = 10;
reading = 0
previousreading = 0

# PyAudio Object
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

while True:
        stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
        frames = []

        for i in range(0, int(RATE/CHUNK*RECORD_SECONDS)):
                data = stream.read(70)
                frames.append(data)
                time.sleep(0.001)

        reading = audioop.max(data, 2)
        if reading - previousreading > threshold:
                print(reading)
        previousreading = reading

        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()

# Clearing the resources
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()
```

It mostly works, but there are a number of problems with it.

1. I am having to create and close the audio stream on every loop. This doesn't seem like a good thing to do, but the script fails otherwise.
2. I was expecting to be able to use "data = stream.read(CHUNK)", but the largest amount of data I can read without getting an error is around 70. All of the other examples I've seen online are able to use CHUNK.
3. I really have no idea of how much sound this script is sampling. Like I say, I want to sample and compare 0.1 second samples.
4. The "time.sleep(0.001)" is in there because apparently it reduces processor overhead, but I haven't been able to find the optimum value for this.

Any help in improving the script would be most welcome. I'm happy to share the MQTT side of things (which works fine) with anyone interested in it.

Comment: dunno if its done in hardware however it may lower CPU usage if you lower sample rate ... no need to declare 44100  samples per second for one whole second if you say you want  0.1 second samples ... ditto for RECORD_SECONDS ... also I suggest you remove that sleep step ... if audio callbacks are done properly no need for a sleep

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problems I'm experiencing seem to be related to using the Raspberry Pi. When I run the same program on my Mac it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To add to this. If you are encountering buffer overruns and unpredictable behaviour when using PyAudio on the Raspberry Pi then look to do to things.

Increase the CHUNK size to 4096 and set exception_on_overflow=false. i.e.

```
CHUNK = 4096
for i in range(0, int(RATE/CHUNK/settings.SOUNDRATE)):
data = stream.read(CHUNK,exception_on_overflow=False)
    frames.append(data)
```

Upon doing this my scripts started working reliably.